# windows phone best way to tombstone my list

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have a model with different properties, how can I save this on state and restore after resuming of application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jeff Prosise has a great series of posts on [Real-World Tombstoning in Silverlight for Windows Phone](http://www.wintellect.com/CS/blogs/jprosise/archive/2011/02/07/real-world-tombstoning-in-silverlight-for-windows-phone-part-4.aspx) that should tell you everything you need to know about tombstoning, including what to save, how, and when.